# Continuous Density Functions

Tags: probability, density-function

First of all I know this question has been solved, but none of the online forums really explain it well, I am really confused with this question.

> 1. Suppose you choose at random a real number X from the interval $[2; 10]$.
>
>    (a) Find the density function $f(x)$ and the probability of an event $E$ for this experiment, where $E$ is a subinterval $[a; b]$ of $[2; 10]$.
>
>    (b) From (a), find the probability that $X > 5$, that $5 < X < 7$, and that
>      $X^2 -12X + 35 > 0$.

For instance for part a, $f(x)= 1/8$. Why? If $X$ is chosen from the interval $[2;10]$, which means $2\le x\le 10$, from here there are nine numbers, so why is it $1/8$?

Comment: REAL numbers, not integers.

Comment: This is known as the "Fence Post Error".  If I have *nine* fence posts and place them in a line one metre apart, what length of fencing do I need?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with continuous random variable, not a discrete one.

The interval is a *real number* line segment of length $8$.   The uniform selection of REAL numbers from this interval will thus require a probability density of $\tfrac 1 8$, in order that this integral is unity.

$$\int_{[2;10]} f_X(x)\operatorname d x = \int_2^{10} \frac 1 8 \operatorname d x = 1$$

This leads into (b):

$$\mathsf P(a\leq X\leq b) = \int_a^b \tfrac 1 8\operatorname d x = \frac {b-a}{8} \qquad \mbox{iff }\Big[ 2\leq a\leq b\leq 10\Big]$$

---

PS:

> If $X$ is chosen from the interval $[2;10]$, which means $2≤x≤10$, from here there are nine numbers, so why is it $1/8$ ?

As mentioned above, you are dealing with a real number interval, so there are *many, many, many* more real numbers in the interval than those integers.   As to why the interval is of length $8$ when there are *nine* integers in the interval, refer to what is known as the "Fence Post Error".

Consider this: If I have *nine* fence posts placed in a line *one* metre apart, what length of fencing do I need?

Answer (score 0):

From the first sentence we obtain that there is given a random variable $X:\Omega\to [2;10]$ such that for any Lebesgue measurable $A\subset[2;10]$ one has
$$\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\frac{\int_A1dx}{\int_{[2;10]}1dx}=\frac{|A|}{8},$$
where by $|A|$ I denote the one dimensional Lebesgue measure.

a) By definition a density function of a random variable $X$ is a Lebesgue measurable function defined on $X(\Omega)$ such that for
$$\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\int_Af(x)dx.$$

Getting back to our problem we look for $f$ such that
$$\frac{|A|}{8}=\int_Af(x)dx.$$
Clearly $f(x)\equiv\frac{1}{8}$, satisfies the above condition. To answer the second part of a) we compute
$$\mathbb{P}(X\in[a;b])=\int_{[a;b]}f(x)dx=\frac{b-a}{8}.$$

b) We have
$$\mathbb{P}(X > 5)=\int_{(5;10]}f(x)dx=\frac{10-5}{8}=\frac{5}{8},\\
\mathbb{P}(5 < X < 7)=\int_{(5;7)}f(x)dx=\frac{7-5}{8}=\frac{1}{4}.\\
$$
To compute the last probability we first solve the inequality $x^2-12x+25>0$ for $x\in[2;10]$. The roots of the quadratic function are $x_{1,2}=6\pm\sqrt{6}$, so the solution is $x\in[2;6-\sqrt{6})\cup(6+\sqrt{6};10]$. Finally
$$\mathbb{P}(X^2-12X+25>0)=\mathbb{P}(X\in[2;6-\sqrt{6})\cup(6+\sqrt{6};10])=\int_{[2;6-\sqrt{6})\cup(6+\sqrt{6};10]}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{8}(6-\sqrt{6}-2+10-(6+\sqrt{6}))=\frac{1}{8}(8-2\sqrt{6})=1-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4}.$$

Comment: While I'm sure the work is correct, I believe introducing Lebesgue measurability into your answer is beyond the scope of the OP's course based on this question and others the OP has asked. While Lebesgue measurability is important for defining random variables, I don't see much necessity to introduce it here.